# Iterate through array of any type

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, enums

I have an array of enums, for example:

```
let arr: [Any] = [Components.self, Periphery.self]
```

After iteration over it i want something like this:

```
for element in arr {
    let something = element.someSpecificProperty
}
```

Probably, I need some function which can return me a specific type. When i write

> "element.something"

, exactly in this moment i need to know a type of this element. How can i achieve this?

Comment: if let something = element as? ClassOfElement { }

Comment: Finally, i made a protocol and confirmed all my class to that protocol and then i can get all what a want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure want do you want but this works:

```
let arr: [Any] = [UIView.self, URL.self]
for element in arr {
    let something = (element as? AnyObject)!
    print("\(type(of:something.self))")
}
```

Comment: I want to get a specific type. You downcast to any type but i need a specific!